# What is the difference of nuance between the statements: “Why had they not already killed their hostage? and “Why didn’t they kill their hostage”?

Tags: meaning, grammar

There was the following statement in (April 24) Time magazine’s article titled, “Thanks for dumb terrorists” reporting the capture of Boston bomb attack suspects: http://swampland.time.com/2013/04/21/give-thanks-for-dumb-terrorists/#ixzz2REueMOq5

> “**Why had they not already killed him?** If the allegations against the
>   Tsarnaevs are true, they were obviously quite capable of killing in
>   cold blood. Assuming they had his ATM pin number, the owner of the
>   Mercedes no longer served any obvious use to them. What’s more, he
>   knew exactly who they were: The Tsarnaevs had reportedly identified
>   themselves as the marathon bombers.”

What difference would come up by saying “Why had they not already killed him?” instead of a simpler version, “Why didn’t they kill him (then)”? Is there a very big difference?

As we don’t have ‘the past perfect tense – have /had +p.p.’ mode in our language, it’s pretty difficult for me to discern the exact difference of the nuance of messages in two different tenses.

Comment: At a glance it looks like the sentence was revised from "Why hadn't they already killed him?", to exclude the contraction "hadn't".  Though, there may be some argument here for "simple past" versus "present perfect" tenses

Comment: Isn't it an argument for 'simple past' versus 'past perfect' tenses?

Comment: Right you are.  Yesterday I experienced an unfortunate coffee drought.

Comment: @ Yoichi: It's important to note that the reporter specifically and deliberately used the word "already". Idiomatically, Simple Past doesn't work very well with "already", but Past Perfect does. Which probably accounts for GB having only 8 hits for [why did they not already](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22why+did+they+not+already%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (simple past, do-support for "infinitive"), but 551 for [why had they not already](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22why+had+they+not+already%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) past perfect, have-support for past participle)

Comment: @dotsamuelswan. What does 'experience an unfortunate coffee drought' mean just for my curiosity? Is it something like a hangover?

Comment: @YoichiOishi It means I didn't drink any coffee, due to it being unavailable at the office.  We ran out.  This is not by any stretch a common phrase or idiom.  It is just the way I chose to word my *"lack of coffee"* situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article uses Past Perfect because the "narrative time" at that point is focussed on

> ...the carjacking victim “managed to escape”...

...in the preceding paragraph. That's to say, the reporter is asking why the Tsarnaevs hadn't *already* killed the victim, at some *earlier* time before he escaped.

I note OP's suggestion includes the word "then". But note that the reporter isn't asking why they didn't kill him *when* or *after* he "started escaping". He's specifically asking why they didn't do this some time *after* getting the ATM pin number and car, but *before* letting him get free.

Using Simple Past is perfectly valid, but doesn't convey the narrative sequence quite so precisely.